# The program has unexpectedly finished - app crashed

Tags: qt, qml

I have a problem with Qt Charts in QML modeling. I have a simple application that implements a very simple ChartView. As I run the application, it crashed and I get the error in Application Output `The program has unexpectedly finished`.

I added in my src.pro

```
QT += qml quickcontrols2 charts
```

and my applications is this

```
import QtCharts 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ChartView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBrownSand
        antialiasing: true

        PieSeries {
            id: pieSeries
            PieSlice { label: "eaten"; value: 94.9 }
            PieSlice { label: "not yet eaten"; value: 5.1 }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I have this problem?

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: Check the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html#getting-started).

Answer (score 5):

Check if you are using `QGuiApplication` instead of `QApplication` in your main.cpp.

The following example works properly, but it crashes if we use `QGuiApplication` in `main()`:

> Note: Since Qt Creator 3.0 the project created with Qt Quick Application wizard based on Qt Quick 2 template uses QGuiApplication by default. As Qt Charts utilizes Qt Graphics View Framework for drawing, QApplication must be used. The project created with the wizard is usable with Qt Charts after the QGuiApplication is replaced with QApplication.

More info [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmlmodule.html).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->setSource(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQml 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ChartView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBrownSand
        antialiasing: true

        PieSeries {
            id: pieSeries
            PieSlice { label: "eaten"; value: 94.9 }
            PieSlice { label: "not yet eaten"; value: 5.1 }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why it crashes?how stupid is qt?There are so many shortcomings in qt

Comment: @mohsen According to Qt, as Qt Charts utilizes Qt Graphics View Framework for drawing, QApplication must be used.